# How can I detect if qBittorrent is downloading?

Tags: linux, windows, batch, shell-script, qbittorrent

How can I write a batch/script file to query [qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/) to find out whether or not it is downloading something?

Depending on the outcome, I would like to execute further commands.

Answer (score 5):

Below are two pieces of code (one for Windows and one for Linux) which use the [qBittorrent v4.1 (or later) API](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Web-API-Documentation) to return a message depending on whether or not something is downloading.

### Windows

```
@echo off

rem Remove existing cookie jar
del /F %temp%\cookies.txt 2>nul

rem Login to qBittorrent
curl -s -b %temp%\cookies.txt -c %temp%\cookies.txt --header "Referer: http://localhost:8080" --data "username=admin&password=secret" http://localhost:8080/api/v2/auth/login >nul

rem Get list of downloading torrents
curl -s -b %temp%\cookies.txt -c %temp%\cookies.txt --header "Referer: http://localhost:8080" "http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info" | jq | findstr """state""" | findstr /R "stalledDL downloading metaDL" >nul

if errorlevel 0 (
    echo Something downloading
) else (
    echo Nothing downloading
)

rem Remove used cookie jar
del /F %temp%\cookies.txt 2>nul
```

### Linux

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove existing cookie jar
rm -f ~/.cookies.txt

# Login to qbittorrent
curl -s -b ~/.cookies.txt -c ~/.cookies.txt --header "Referer: http://localhost:8080" --data "username=admin&password=secret" http://localhost:8080/api/v2/auth/login >/dev/null 2>&1

# Get list of downloading torrents
if [[ $(curl -s -b ~/.cookies.txt -c ~/.cookies.txt --header "Referer: http://localhost:8080" "http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info" | jq . | grep "state" | egrep "(stalledDL|downloading|metaDL)") ]]; then
        echo "Something downloading"
else
        echo "Nothing downloading"
fi

# Remove used cookie jar
rm -f ~/.cookies.txt
```

### Some points to note about both versions

- You need to enable the web UI within qBittorrent and set a username and password.
- The code has the username `admin` with the password `secret`, you'll want to change those
- The code connects to `localhost:8080`, you'll need to change all instances of this to the correct machine name/IP and port number
- We create a cookie jar (called `cookies.txt`) for holding the SID. This is given to us after a successful login and must be sent when executing further commands. Once we've finished with it, the cookie jar is deleted.
- There's no error handling, if something fails it'll probably (and possibly incorrectly) report "Something downloading"
- This code considers the states of `stalledDL`, `downloading` and `metaDL` to be downloading. You can change this by looking at the various states documented [here](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-Documentation#get-torrent-list).
- `jq` takes the JSON ouput from the qBittorrent API and formats it in a way which is easier to read/parse.

### Some points specific to the Windows version

- If you aren't running Windows 10 then you'll need to install [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/)
- You'll need to download [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), rename it to just `jq.exe` and place it in the same folder as this script - personally I put it in `C:\Windows\System32` so it works from any folder
- `jq` is essential because the output from qBittorrent can consist of extremely long lines, which `findstr` cannot handle (and throws an error).

### Some points specific to the Linux version

- The code used curl, which is usually available by default. If not, then on Debian you can use `sudo apt-get install curl`
- You'll need to install `jq` for this to work and it's available in most repositories. On Debian this is `sudo apt-get install jq`
- If you feel inclined `jq` isn't technically needed and the `egrep` can be modified to filter both the state and value